# Unable log in to the index.html

Tags: java, spring-boot, security

I just Cloned the Spring boot project from Github [Link](https://github.com/MarcinU2K/hbs-spring-boot-jpa-mysql-thymeleaf-)
As he said in the README.md , `Login: admin Password: password`,but when I started the project and input that, this page show up[image]

How to get to the index.html page?
the SecurityConfig.java:

```
package com.hbs.security;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String HBS_ADMIN = "/hbs/**";
    private static final String HBS_USER = "/hbs/*";
    private static final String ADMIN = "ADMIN";
    private static final String USER = "USER";

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception{
        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HBS_ADMIN).hasRole(ADMIN)
                .antMatchers(HBS_USER).hasRole(USER)
            .and()
                .formLogin();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("admin").password("password").roles(ADMIN)
                .and()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles(USER);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well it's hard to say what is wrong. We cannot see your code. Is there any exception in console ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type this url in your web browser:

http://localhost:8080/hbs/

And put

**login:admin**

**password:password**

I just download this project and it's working without problems and I can log into the system. This error says that you don't have privileges to open requested page. When I tried to logged with login: user I has this error so try to use admin account

If you really logged as Admin and this error appears it means that you change something in Spring Security configuration (com.hbs.security.SecurityConfig.java) so if this error appears please put your code of this class

Comment: I just added Spring Security configuration source code, and check the name and password again and again, still can't log in :(

Comment: oh I just added the http in front of localhost, and it's working! thank you so much!!I don't know the http is neccesary...

Comment: Good to know :-)